# Using ArcGIS Pro Login Methods

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, authentication

By default, ArcGIS Pro uses **Named User** license type provided through user membership in an **ArcGIS Online organization** or in an in **ArcGIS Enterprise**

[image]

The thing which confusing me is this part `Your ArcGIS organization's URL`!

[image]

What kind of user is this?

Aren't the `ArcGIS Online` and `ArcGIS Organization` same thing?

If so then why we are not using the credentials — User name and Password — in first ArcGIS Login User name and Password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a type of user, it's a type of authentication that is the difference between the "ArcGIS Login" and the "Your ArcGIS Organization's URL" methods.

ArcGIS Login method will authenticate agains ArcGIS Online's own directory of users.  The directory is a global directory for all ArcGIS Online users across the world.  Company accounts will often have their company name appended to the username (eg, first.last@companyname.com_companyname) to make sure that the usernames a globally unique).

Your ArcGIS Organization's URL method will work with whatever particular settings have been configured in your organisation's ArcGIS Online account.  This will often mean that using your actual company email address without the extra suffix as the username, but more importantly, it allows authentication to be done against your company's own directory service (such as LDAP, Active Directory, SAML, Office365, etc).  This means that you can use the same usernames/passwords as every other system in your company.  But to do so, you'll need to specify your specific AGOL company URL.

Comment: Thanks for reply Son of a Beach, So If a company, for example, didn't even set up the `ArcGIS Online organization` and thy just have `ArcGIS Enterprise (Portal)`, ArcGIS Online still have the Named User in it's  global directory like (eg, first.last@companyname.com_companyname)? How we can check this then?

Comment: Sorry, I did not account for Portal in my answer.  I don’t use Enterprise/Portal, so can’t give a knowledgeable answer to your comment.